# Save surface to file without DirectX(d3dx9_43.dll)

Tags: c++, directx, screenshot, direct3d

I making a program that takes screenshots, I use `GetFrontBufferData` and `D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile`. But now I am facing trouble.`D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile` uses d3dx9_43.dll, that cannot be static linked, and program didn't work on pc without directx. How I can save surface, using only D3D?

Comment: @StephenReindl I've already try this http://realmike.org/blog/projects/taking-screenshots-with-direct3d-8/ , but it give me broken bmp file, source program also do this.

Comment: The ScreenShot module in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) does exactly this... for Direct3D 11. You could adapt it for Direct3D 9.

Answer (score 0):

`GetFrontBufferData` gets you a pointer to the `IDirect3DSurface9`. Calling `IDirect3DSurface9::GetDesc` will give you `D3DSURFACE_DESC`, describing the image data. Most important for saving it to a file are `Format`, `Width` and `Height` members. Then, you can call `IDirect3DSurface9::LockRect` to obtain the actual data. The output of this function is a `D3DLOCKED_RECT`, which contains the image data in the `pBits` member. Note that the image data might not be tightly packed, you will have to take into account the `Pitch` member of the `D3DLOCKED_RECT`. You can then use any static linkable image library, (eg. DevIL) to write the image out to disk, or roll-your-own image writer (writing a BMP/TGA is quite easy).

Or, you could just install the proper DirectX runtime on the target computer, which would probably be a lot easier.